# AngularJS - update isolated scope variable from link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have encountered problem with updating data in AngularJS directive.

The directive loads list of orders when initialized, and then watches the variable `orderMade`. If this variable is changed, it should reload the list of orders.

```
.directive('listRingorders', ['ringsService',function(ringsService){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl : 'pages/list-ringorders.tpl.html',
    scope : { 
        orderMade : '='
    },                                                                      
    controllerAs : 'RingOrderListCtrl',
    bindToController: true,
    controller : function (){

    // variables
    var self = this;

    // load data
    ringsService.fetchRingOrders()
        .then(function(data){
          self.ringorders = data;
        }, function(data){
          alert("Error");
      });

      //log orders
      this.test = function(){
        console.log(self.ringorders);
      }

    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.orderMade, function() {
                ringsService.fetchRingOrders()
                  .then(function(data){
                        scope.ringorders = data;
                   }, function(data){
                        alert("Error");
                });
            });
        }
  }
}]);
```

And here is html template (simplyfied)

```
<div ng-repeat="ringOrder in RingOrderListCtrl.ringorders">
  <h3>Order number: {{ringOrder.ID}}</h3>
</div>
```

I can correctly capture changing value `orderMade` and reload data, but when I update the `scope.ringorders` variable, the list does not update (HTML page shows the same data). Also when I log `self.ringorders` in `controller`'s `test()` function, it contains old data.

My question is: how to update directive's `scope` data from `link` function?

**UPDATE**

I have figured out the solution - I was accessing the scope of `controller` function in directive instead of accesing teh scope of directive itself.

Here is correct template (just replace `RingOrderListCtrl.ringorders` with `ringorders`)

```
<div ng-repeat="ringOrder in ringorders">
  <h3>Order number: {{ringOrder.ID}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `scope.$apply()` in your `then` method after you added ringorders to scope?

Comment: Calling `scope.$apply` causes `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Comment: OK, then the digest is already in progress. Sometimes it helps with asynch data. Where have you added your test method call? Can you please add the code of your `ringService` maybe that helps to see the issue?

Comment: thanks, I have just found the solution - turned out I was accesing wrong scope - see updated question

Comment: Well, about two minutes too late :/ glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're binding data to two different places (the controller, via controllerAs and onto `scope`). In your directive's link function, you can access the directive's controller by passing in a fourth argument:

```
link: function listRingOrdersLink(scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch(function() {
        /**
         * bindToController puts this info 
         * on the controller object
         */
        return ctrl.orderMade;
     }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        ringService.fetchRingOrders()
            .then(function(data) {
                /** put the new data on the controller */
                ctrl.ringorders = data;
            }, function(data) { alert(data); });
     });
}
```